# Given a*b, c*d , how can I prove a+b>c+d(fact)?

Tags: number-theory

In situation, there are two positive numbers a,b,c,d and it is satisfied with a+b>c+d.(this is fact) 
When we only know the values a*b, c*d (we don't know a,b,c,d respectively),
how can we prove this fact a+b>c+d?

for example, a=2,b=8,c=3,d=6  => a+b(10)>c+d(9).
but we only know a*b(16), c*d(18). how can we know the fact a+b>c+d? 
thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably should be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also that's probably a bad example and/or you missed a part of the explanation, because with ab=16 and cd=18 you can have a=4, b=4, c=2, d=9 in which case a+b (8) > c+d (11) does not stand

Comment: However if you know ab =16, cd=18 and the fact that a+b>c+d, then you may be able to list the possible values of a,b,c and d. Is that what you want? (In this case, just list the possible factors of 16 and 18, then discard the ones that do not respect a+b>c+d such as the one I commented above)